# Reduce from RxJS doesn't return Object

Tags: angular, rxjs

I'm working on Angular and I the `reduce()`operator doesn't return my object. My code is following below:

I've created an interface

```
interface Example {
  page?: number;
  size?: number;
  name?: string;
}
```

And  I declared a subject to create a data stream and inside of pipe operator, I wanna create a object from the data which I sent through the `this.example$.next()`.

```
exemple$ = new Subject<Example>();

  get$ = this.exemple$
    .pipe(
      startWith({}),
      reduce(
        (obj, item) => {
          Object.keys(item).forEach(data => (obj[data] = item[data]));
          console.log('obj', obj);
          return obj;
        },
        { page: 15, size: 10 } as Example
      ),
      tap(console.log)
    )
    .subscribe();

  ngOnInit() {
    this.exemple$.next({ name: 'John Paul' });
  }
```

When the Angular starts up, It send the data and I catch it in `console.log()` inside of `reducer()` operator and `tap()` operator.

I can see the data inside of `reduce()` but nothing happens inside of `tap()` . Its like as reduce is not returning the object which I'm returning inside it.

Can anyone help me?
Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your source Observable is `exemple$` which is a Subject. The [`reduce()`](https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/reduce) operator will emit only after the source Observable completes which means you need to call `exemple$.complete()` (or have some condition that completes the chain).

Maybe you're looking for [`scan()`](https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/scan) instead that emits all intermediate results?

Comment: Thx a lot, @martin. Your solution salve me!!